# DOMDocument saveHTML incorrectly encoding href attributes

Tags: php, html, domdocument

I am using DOMDocument to load some user contributed HTML blocks and then manipulate them.  It appears (assuming I am doing everything correctly) that DOMDocument is running the urls inside an href attribute through htmlentities.  This is making my anchor tags which have ampersands in the query string come out incorrect.

Example:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<a href="http://foo.com?bar=baz&foo=bar">Foo</a>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

The output becomes(notice the & in the url was converted to `&amp;`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body><a href="http://foo.com?bar=baz&amp;foo=bar">Foo</a></body></html>
```

Additionally, during the call to `$dom->loadHTML($html);` the following warnings were output...

> Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in
>   Entity, line: 1

I have no idea what that means.

Am I missing something?

Comment: It means your HTML is invalid to start with -- those `&`s should have been `&amp;`s.

Comment: A bare '&' *anywhere* in HTML has *never ever been valid since the beginning of time*, and *still isn't* ([try it yourself](http://html5.validator.nu)). It is only because everyone does it incorrectly that browsers have parsed this laxly and HTML5 created the "(un)ambiguous ampersand" concepts to formalize this parsing so that error-recovery and the parsed DOM will be consistent across browsers. But you should ***always*** write `&amp;`! (Sorry, this is one of my bad-HTML pet-peeves.)

Comment: @FrancisAvila Thanks. I didn't think this was the case within href attributes since that is not rendering markup to the browser but instead defining a url, which & is a perfectly legal character.  You are correct though.  Since my content is coming from users, who will undoubtedly produce examples like mine, is there a way to get DOMDocument to ignore this case and not produce a warning or must I resort to the error suppression in php (@ symbol)?

Comment: If your content is coming from users, you should run their input through [tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) first, or better yet parse with [html5lib](http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/) instead of the [stock `DOM` library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). (Also you should scold your users with a quick HTML tutorial.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ampersand symbol is used in valid/compliant XHTML to determine HTML entity characters.

See this reference list:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp

Your DOMDocument is complaining as it has detected an invalid character definition on the way in, and corrected it on the way out.